# How to return all possible combination

Tags: python

I have multiple array like following

```
A[0] = [a1, a2, a3]
A[1] = [b1, b2]
...
A[k-1] = [k1, ...]
```

I would like to generate all the vector `[a?, b?, ..., k?]` possible
I looked at itertool library, but it does not feet my need.

How can I simply do it. (I though about recursion but I guess there is a more simpler solution).

Comment: what about using generators ?

Comment: I looked at itertools library but i overlooked product function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product


for vector in product(*A):
    # vector is [a[0], b[0], ..., k[0]] through to [a[k-1], [b[k-1], ..., k[k-1]]
    # odometer style
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> A = [[1, 2, 3], ['foo', 'bar'], ['spam', 'eggs']]
>>> for vector in product(*A):
...     print vector
... 
(1, 'foo', 'spam')
(1, 'foo', 'eggs')
(1, 'bar', 'spam')
(1, 'bar', 'eggs')
(2, 'foo', 'spam')
(2, 'foo', 'eggs')
(2, 'bar', 'spam')
(2, 'bar', 'eggs')
(3, 'foo', 'spam')
(3, 'foo', 'eggs')
(3, 'bar', 'spam')
(3, 'bar', 'eggs')
```

Comment: Thanks, I looked at itertools library, but i didnt notice it was what i was looking at. I will give a try.